# Windows Phone: Adding Slider to LongListSelector

Tags: windows-mobile

I am trying to develop an app that shows several small images in a longlistselector. In front of each image there is a slider to set the time that each image should be presented. I am trying to add slider into the longlistselector in the XMAL file however, there is an error.

Could you please give a simple code that shows me how can I add the slider to longlistselector?

Thanks,
Bahador